# Having trouble with swipe gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe

I'm having a weird reaction in 1 of my view when swipe to back.
It did not go back to my previous page but other pages does not have this issue. Also, it perform the previous page viewWillAppear code after the swipe.

I did not set any custom back buttons for the views but it is having different effect.

**--Edit--**

In my previous page that call the affecting page

```
ViewControllerA *view = [[ViewControllerA alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerA" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

In my affecting page I only declare viewDidLoad function.

All my navigation for other classes is using the above calling.

By normal clicking the back action at the navigation bar, it will go back to the previous page normally.

**--Edit 2--**

My current setup is ViewA > ViewB > ViewC where ViewC is where the bug is happening.

At ViewB when I swipe at the edge, it can go back to ViewA.
At ViewC when I swipe at the edge, viewWillAppear in ViewB called but ViewB is not shown.

Tried putting @kaushal answer

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
     self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
     self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate;   //check UIGestureRecognizerDelegate delegate set properly.
}
```

in both ViewB and ViewC but it did not trigger.

**--Edit 3--**

I tested my other features flow and it seems that some have this same problem upon entering the third view and some is on the forth view.

Comment: Can you please share your code for others to look at it?

Comment: can you put more info?

Answer (score 0):

In ViewDidAppear: use this code :

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
     self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
     self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate;   //check UIGestureRecognizerDelegate delegate set properly.
 }
```

And check UIGestureRecognizerDelegate is not nil.

Comment: The code inside did not trigger. I also tested by putting it in my calling class. It did not trigger also.

Comment: Can you pls check with modified condition in comment  if ([self. navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) { }. There is no other way as this is apple default gesture to VC which handle swipe to pop on navigation VC.

Comment: Tested with the modified condition. This time it got perform the inside if statement but it still will not handle the swipe to pop.

Comment: great! Now before pushing VC add watch point to self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate and observe where it was getting nil, since your gesture is working with other VC, so there might me a chances of setting it nil somewhere. you can add watchpoint to self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer for debug.

Comment: Is watchpoint = breakpoint? How do I check for that variable? Izzit check on the Thread area? When I hover over self variable it did not show the variable

Comment: Watchpoint is differ from breakpoint, it will notify you like breakpoint when value changed for variable. set watchpoint using lldb command - watch set variable self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer. make sure your variable in scope that point.

Comment: to get lldb console, you have to pause you code with break point, pls google  it for more detail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126690/discussion-between-kar-wai-and-kaushal).